# Unit testing an AngularJS directive that contains $watch() not being compiled

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs

I'm currently researching my problem but I thought adding a question here may help as I'm new to AngularJS and even newer to Unit Testing.

I have the current directive that works, it users the `$watch()` function to track a variable, if the variable is not present a default message is provided, for example "Deleted User Value" ...

```
angular.module('myModule')


.directive('displayName', function ($transform) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            displayName: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element) {
            scope.$watch('displayName', function(value){
                if(!value) {
                    element.html($transform('users.profile.deletedUser'));
                } else {
                    element.html(value);
                }
            });
        }
    };
})

;
```

and I have the following unit test (please note that I have amended this on the advice of Maurice) :

```
beforeEach(module('myModule'));

beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope) {
    $scope = $rootScope;
    element = angular.element('<div class="name" display-name="name"></div>');
    $compile(element)($scope);
}));


it('should display the deleted user name', inject(function() {
    $scope.displayName = null;
    element.scope().$apply();
    console.log(element);
    expect(element.html()).toBe('Deleted User Value');

}));
```

However I am getting the following issue: `TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property`. and the `console.log` is not being outputted, can anyone advise where I am going wrong? Sorry for my stupidity but I am trying to learn unit testing "on the job" and I am still very new to AngularJS

Comment: Is there a typo at the top? `$tranform` should be `$transform`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There seem to be several things wrong with the code.

The directive has a dependency on `$translate` which isn't used while a `$transform` is used but not injected.

Secondly in your second test you are calling `element.$scope().$apply();`. That should be `element.scope().$apply();` instead.

Finally you are setting the `displayName` property on the scope but binding to the `name` property in the test code using `<div class="name" display-name="name"></div>`.

I would write the tests something like this:

```
describe("The displayName directive", function () {
    var $scope, element;

    beforeEach(module('myModule'));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($compile, $rootScope) {
        $scope = $rootScope;
        element = angular.element('<div class="name" display-name="name"></div>');
        $compile(element)($scope);
    }));

    it('should display the deleted user name', function () {
        element.scope().$apply();
        expect(element.text()).toBe('users.profile.deletedUser');

    });

    it('should display the actual user name', function () {
        $scope.name = "Maurice";
        element.scope().$apply();
        expect(element.text()).toBe('Maurice');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have amended the transform/translate issue, I have amended my code but still no joy, I shall amend the code above

Comment: Once again, thanks for the advice: I have amended my code but still no joy, I still get TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property on the first test (I haven't tried the second yet)

Comment: I would advise taking a good look at the stack trace or stepping through the code with the Chrome debugging tools to see where the error occurs.

Comment: This seems to work, it's when I introduce the third party transform/translate modules into the tests I get errors. Thanks for the advice, now I have to move on to adapting the tests with transform/translate (pascalprecht.translate). Thanks for everything